# OmniSharp fails to load with vscode version 1.18.0 update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

yesterday vscode updated to 1.18.0. I've been working with vscode for a little over a month now without any problems. since this new update, omnisharp quietly fails to load.
I don't see any kind of log or error message.
If I try to run the command, "OmniSharp: Select Project" an error pops up saying "Error spawn UNKNOWN"
If I try to run the command, "Omnisharp: Restart OmniSharp" nothing happens. No error, nothing in the output window.
Is there a log somewhere that might have more details?
I have already tried to re-install the extensions with the exact same results.
I have already tried to re-install vscode with the exact same results.
I'm not finding any other posts with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was [not specific](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37994) to OmniSharp after [all](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37863):

> roblourens commented 7 days ago
>
> We are simply publishing the 64-bit
>   version of ripgrep with the 32-bit build, which is only an issue on an
>   actual 32-bit OS. Will be fixed in next Insiders/update.

Can be fixed by replacing `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules\vscode-ripgrep\bin\rg.exe` with proper 32-bit version from [ripgrep releases](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases)

Comment: Is this only limited to 32 bit windows? I ran into the same issue after update to 1.18  and am running Windows 10 x64 and the only solution I found was to revert back to 1.17.

Comment: @pri0ritize, Probably not very helpful, but if you're seeing this issue on x64 windows, then something else might be wrong.

Comment: Not that it's necessary, but maybe someone will happen across this. The issue in VS Code beyond 1.17 was having a Visual Studio 2015 installation. Removing the VS 2015 installation completely solved the Unity Intellisense/Omnisharp issue.